# Adding opacity to series-chart dc js

Tags: dc.js

How do I add opacity to the series-chart, in the similar way that it exists in scatter-plot and splom?

Primarily, I have the brush in the series chart similar to the one that exists in scatter-plot but cannot seem to get the opacity of the excluded points sorted out.

Comment: I think you'll find that the brushing is not working at all, since the scatter-series will display a horizontal brush but the scatter plot needs a 2D brush (and further, the scatter series chart requires a different shape of data from the plain scatter plot). I don't have time to look into this today, but I think it's fixable.

Comment: So I'm primarily trying to use the brush and opacity from the scatter chart and adding that to series chart. I could add the brush to the series chart but the opacity is something I've not been able to add as a feature to the series chart.